# Running gRPC server on Raspberry Pi with SSL

Tags: ssl, raspberry-pi, arm, grpc, grpc-java

I could not start a gRPC server (written in Java) on Raspberry Pi with SSL security enabled. I get the the following message:

```
2019-07-01 13:39:29,988 [main                     ] DEBUG OpenSsl                   Failed to load netty-tcnative; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable, unless the application has already loaded the symbols by some other means. See http://n
etty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html for more information.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32, netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32_fedora, netty_tcnative_arm_32, netty_tcnative]
```

I think the netty tcnative boringssl is not build for ARM processors. But what is the alternative?
Can i configure something else in maven?

Answer (score 0):

See the [gRPC SECURITY.md documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#tls-on-non-android). For ARM it is easiest to use Java 9+. Java 9+ tends to perform better as well, since many Java 7/8s were interpreted on ARM.